# How do I place an array into a checkbox and click on it according to the array id react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

When I click 1 checkbox, all values checkbox are checked too, then my question is how to separate it according to the value of the array?

[image]

```
render () {
    const { data } = this.props
    const { checked, statusChecked, unhide } = this.state

    const checkBoxCourier = data.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Card key={index} style={globalStyle.padDefault}>
          <Item>
            <Text>
              {'[LOGO] '}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.bold}>{item.courier_name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
          </Item>
          {
            item.services.map((item2, index) => (
              <ListItem
                key={index}
              >
                <CheckBox
                  checked={checked}
                  onPress={() => this.onCheckBoxPress(item2.courier_service_id, item2.status)}
                />
                <View style={styles.row}>
                  <Body>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item2.service_name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item2.service_description}</Text>
                  </Body>
                </View>
              </ListItem>
            ))
          }
        </Card>
      )
    })

    return (
      <Container>
        <ScrollView>
          {checkBoxCourier}
        </ScrollView>
      </Container>
    )
```

Comment: can you please provide code..

Comment: theres my code sir ...

Answer (score 1):

you do by this way

```
checked={index+item2.courier_service_id == this.state.Selected ? checked :uncheck}
          onPress={() => this.onCheckBoxPress(item2,index)}
        />
```

and in onCheckBoxPress

```
  onCheckBoxPress(){
   this.setState({Selected:index+item2.courier_service_id})
    }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: wow, thanks..  it's work, but i wan't to make it multiple checkbox, how is that ?

Comment: the one you give just can only check once sir, i mean wan't to make that checkbox as multiple choice...


In my case before, when I clicked on the 1 checkbox, all of them were checked, all I wanted was to check the components only 1, 
according to the value they have .. thats why i said multiple option checkbox hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a flag to the checkbox that is specific to the service item rather than the component, something like this:

```
render(){
    const {data} = this.props
    const {checked, statusChecked, unhide} = this.state

    const checkBoxCourier = data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Card key={index} style={globalStyle.padDefault}>
                <Item>
                    <Text>
                        {'[LOGO] '}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.bold}>{item.courier_name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                </Item>
                {
                    item.services.map((item2, index) => (
                        <ListItem
                            key={index}
                        >
                            <CheckBox
                                checked={item2.isChecked} // Save the value here
                                onPress={() => this.onCheckBoxPress(item2.courier_service_id, item2.status)}
                            />
                            <View style={styles.row}>
                                <Body>
                                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item2.service_name}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item2.service_description}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </View>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))
                }
            </Card>
        )
    })
```

Comment: is that multiple checkbox ?
I still haven't found a way hehe